# Endpoint timout setting is getting stripped off when deploying car file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.0.2 on MAC OSX 10.7.4.

I am using Carbon Eclipse plugin 1.0.14 in Eclipse 3.7.2.

Typically, when I develop I use Proxy service with Data service. Proxy service does the input validation / transformation before forwarding the request to Data service.

I am making the end point for the Data Service as a Dynamic endpoint and storing it in the registry.

When I deploy the `car` file to server, the endpoint time out configuration is getting stripped off.

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong? Here is the information in the registry and the actual dynamic endpoint configuration in ESB(admin UI)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ds_endpoint">
    <address statistics="enable" trace="disable"
    uri="http://localhost:8280/services/ITLM_DS/ITLM_OP">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <errorCodes>101503,101504,101505</errorCodes>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>1</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            <retryDelay>3</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>
        <timeout>
            <duration>180000</duration>
            <action>fault</action>
        </timeout>
    </address>
```

Dynamic edpoint definition is as follows

```
 <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/ITLM_DS/ITLM_OP" >
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <errorCodes>101503,101504,101505</errorCodes>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

Please help.
thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue in the ESB 4.0.3. When i deploy your exact endpoint as a dynamic endpoint, its timeouts are removed. Seems to be a bug to me in ESB. Will provide you an update  with more info.